# How to use a pipe in a component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a pipe class which returns data based on the arguments you are passing. I know how to use it in my template HTML using the `|` symbol, but I want to use it in my component too.

Is there a way to call a pipe directly from inside a component or a service in Angular 2?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can call your pipe directly in your code by using:

```
YourPipeClass.prototype.transform(value, arg1, arg2);
```

You can call it from inside your component or from anywhere else that imports it.

There is also the `new` way:

```
new SortTodosPipe().transform(value, arg1, arg2);
```

But keep in mind it will create an object, so either save that object for later use or use the `prototype` method.

Anyway you choose, you must add the pipe to your `providers` if you use it inside a component, like so:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [YourPipe]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I would keep the reusable part of what you're trying to do in a separate service, which can then be injected anywhere. This feels like a slippery slope to something less testable and reusable.

Answer (score 2):

I would instance it and call it "transform" method. I would do so:

- because some pipes can be not pure (i.e. not stateless). Such pipes contain a state associated with an instance.
- because dependency injection is supported for pipes so perhaps you need to provide some parameters when instantiate it.

Here is a sample with sample value and parameters:

```
import {FilterPipe} from './my.pipe';

(...)

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  someMethod() {
    var val = [
      { name: 'test', fieldName: 'fieldvalue' },
      (...)
    ];
    var params = [ 'fieldName', 'fieldValue' ];

    var p = new FilterPipe();
    var result = p.transform(val, params);
  }
}
```

In the template this would be used for example this way:

```
<div *ngFor="#elt of val | filter:'fieldName':'fieldValue'">
  {{elt.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I give solutions to solve this question from previous answers:

- First solution from [@Eran Shabi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36816549/1908296) answer:

You can create instance from Pipe class then use it's transform method within component class, Like this

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export class Component {

  method() {
    const date: sting = '24-05-2020';

    const datePipe = new DatePipe();
    const formatedDate = datePipe.transform(date, 'shortTime');
  }
}
```

- Second solution:

You can Provide `DatePipe` using `@component` Tag Or Using `@Module` tag under your Module class for this Component Then using Dependency injection to inject `DatePipe` instance into Component's constructor.

**Example** for Provide `DatePipe` from Component

```js
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class Component {

  Component(private _datePipe: DatePipe) {
  }

  method() {
    const date: sting = '24-05-2020';

    const formatedDate = this._datePipe.transform(date, 'shortTime');
  }
}
```

Example for Provide `DatePipe` under Module like [@Alexander Leonov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41282812/1908296) answer

```js
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppModule { }

@Component({
  ...
})
export class Component {

  Component(private _datePipe: DatePipe) {
  }

  method() {
    const date: sting = '24-05-2020';

    const formatedDate = this._datePipe.transform(date, 'shortTime');
  }
}
```

**Notices:**

- Like Built-in Pipes classes, also your custom Pipe can apply this solutions
- This Solutions apply on Angular v7+, I Don't known is work with Angular v2

Comment: The provider can also be registered at the application module level making it available to any component.

Comment: @wheredidthatnamecomefrom Yes Correct, I'm already mentioned about that into my second way but without example as I direct to Alexander Leonov answer into another similar question[https://stackoverflow.com/a/41282812/1908296]. OK I updated my answer with example for each option.