# How to use angular2 built-in date pipe in services and directives script files

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-services, date-pipe

I want to use angular2's date pipe in services and directives script files(not only in HTML).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Can't upload code cos some policy restrictions, sorry about that.

Comment: @Community, what I want ask is how to use angular2 date pipe in services and directives not only in component which is different with question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816548/how-to-use-a-pipe-in-a-component-in-angular-2 now, so please help to correct your tag.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Since CommonModule does not export it as a provider you'll have to do it yourself. This is not very complicated.

1) Import DatePipe:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

2) Include DatePipe in your module's providers:

```
NgModule({
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

or component's providers:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class HomeComponent {
...
```

3) Inject it into your component's constructor like any other service:

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
}
```

4) Use it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.time = this.datePipe.transform(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Alexander, it works for me, but I need to import DatePipe like this`import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common/src/pipes';` otherwise webstorm will show an error.

Comment: @LarryChen, this just means that there's something else wrong with your setup, mine does understand it. May be you're using old version of ng2 or WebStorm.

Comment: my version:`"@angular/common": "^2.3.0"`, webstorm: 2016.3.2

Answer (score 35):

In your component

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

If you are using Angular 2, 4 version, try

```js
new DatePipe().transform(myDate, 'yyyy-dd-MM');
```

If you are using Angular 6 and above

```js
new DatePipe('en-US').transform(myDate, 'yyyy-dd-MM');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Avnesh, I found the constructor of DatePipe is `constructor(_locale: string)`, your suggestion missed a parameter, but anyway it inspired me a lot.

Comment: Sample Code combining both answers
`new DatePipe('en-US').transform(myDate, 'yyyy-dd-MM');`

Comment: Please edit to add locale as @Chimu has shown

Comment: @Avnesh Shakya Lcan you tell me how to add  "America/Los_Angeles" time in above function?

Comment: @KapilSoni see this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731783/angular-date-pipe-with-time-zone-information-like-america-edmonton

Comment: @AvneshShakya sir i have tried code but its give ne different time  const text = new Date(this.salesOrderModel.PostingDate).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone:'America/Los_Angeles'});