# Use Angular Basic pipes within components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to use Angular readymade pipe (i.e. date, uppercase) in my Ionic project within a component, but it gives an error.

I have a component folder inside the src/app folder. The components are each in their own folder with scss, html, and ts files.

```
<div class="day">
  {{ day | date }}
</div>
<div class="month">
  {{ month | uppercase }}
</div>
```

Do I have to import the DateModule somewhere?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you please add that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41282812/495157 You may like this too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330319/angular2-setting-date-field-on-reactive-form/45330707#45330707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any module named as DateModule.

The [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) is part of the CommonModule (see @angular/common package).

The CommonModule exports are re-exported by BrowserModule, which is included automatically in the root AppModule (Also in Ionic projects).

Answer (score 0):

**you can see pipes lise from below link : https://angular.io/guide/pipes**

below are list of pipe name and usecase.

DatePipe: Formats a date value according to locale rules.

UpperCasePipe: Transforms text to all upper case.

LowerCasePipe: Transforms text to all lower case.

CurrencyPipe: Transforms a number to a currency string, formatted according to locale rules.

DecimalPipe: Transforms a number into a string with a decimal point, formatted according to locale rules.

PercentPipe: Transforms a number to a percentage string, formatted according to locale rules.