# angular: date pipe with time zone information like America/Edmonton

Tags: angular, pipe

In my Angular application, I need to show some Date/Time information based on specific time zone.

The orginal date/time is based on UTC like "2021-05-24T01:53:00+00:00". And I create JS `Date` object on it. And in the UI, I need to display it for a specific time zone.

I investigate some document, noticed that angular's `date` pipe can support time zone, like:

```
{{todayDate | date:'short':'UTC +4'}}
```

I tried, it can work. But in my case, the time zone data I got is something like: `America/Edmonton`, which can not be supported correclty by the date pipe.

I searched about `America/Edmonton`, not so sure how to convert it to the format which angular date pipe can support.

**Update:**

I have a workaround as below:

add a new method called `getDate`

```
public getDate(date: Date): string {
    return date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"});
}
```

and wrap this function to the original date data like

```
{{getDate(todayDate) | date:'short'}}
```

It can work and the result is correct. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Well, as far as I can say you found the proper and concise way to reach your goal. I wouldn't know any better or shorter way.

Comment: @Chris Bao:sir i tried  -- '2021-11-25T12:17:57'.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}); but its give me same result not working as per timezone can you tell me whats wrong ?